# SemanticKernel throws "Unrecognized request argument supplied: tools"

Tags: c#, openai-api, azure-openai, semantic-kernel

I've just upgraded to **SemanticKernel 1.0.0-rc4** and this error shows up wherever I'm using *Native Functions*:

```
Microsoft.SemanticKernel.Http.HttpOperationException
Unrecognized request argument supplied: tools
Status: 404 (model_error)

Content:
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unrecognized request argument supplied: tools",
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "param": null,
    "code": null
  }
}


Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: REDACTED
x-ms-region: REDACTED
x-ratelimit-remaining-tokens: REDACTED
apim-request-id: REDACTED
X-Request-ID: REDACTED
ms-azureml-model-error-reason: REDACTED
ms-azureml-model-error-statuscode: REDACTED
x-ms-client-request-id: 952ee943-35b4-4bd4-883f-a82c80c93ae3
x-ratelimit-remaining-requests: REDACTED
Strict-Transport-Security: REDACTED
X-Content-Type-Options: REDACTED
Date: Thu, 14 Dec 2023 21:59:26 GMT
Content-Length: 158
Content-Type: application/json
```

Here is my sample code trying to use `LightPlugin` in the sample docs:

```cs
OpenAIPromptExecutionSettings settings = new()
{
    ToolCallBehavior = ToolCallBehavior.AutoInvokeKernelFunctions
};

// This line throws the exception
var result = await chatService.GetChatMessageContentsAsync(chatHistory, settings, kernel);
```

It works fine with semantic functions, the problem is just when I'm using native functions.
The native functions were also working fine in 1.0.0-rc3.

Comment: HTTP error 404 is path not found.  I suspect model_error is the route.  So either the route doesn't exist or you do not have permission to access the route.

Comment: It works fine with semantic functions, the problem is just when I'm using native functions. The native functions were also working fine in rc3.

Comment: You have a credential issue.  The native methods aren't passing through the credentials properly.  Looks like the library has been update in the last few days.  Try latest library : https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel.  See following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/semantic-kernel/overview/

Comment: When was last time code worked?  November  V1.1 was released and following notes : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/semantic-kernel/what-to-expect-from-v1-and-beyond-for-semantic-kernel/ and October notes : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/semantic-kernel/skills-to-plugins-fully-embracing-the-openai-plugin-spec-in-semantic-kernel/

Comment: Maybe post an issue at Github site.  Lots of issues posted yesterday : https://github.com/microsoft/semantic-kernel/issues

Comment: @jdweng Thank you, found the problem. It requires to use a gpt-35-turbo model with a version later than 614. Now I'm using 1106 and it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that since SemanticKernel 1.0.0-rc4, it requires a `gpt-turbo-35` model newer than 0614. Mine was 0301.

Good to mention that in some Azure regions (like **West Europe** at the time) the newer versions are not available yet. I had to create another resource on **UK South** so I could create a 1106 version model.